# jQuery css() not applying

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, onclick

```
<a href="https://www.timeatthebar.co.uk" target="_blank"><img id="icon-img" src="assets/img/tabicon2.png" class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" style="max-width:113px; top: 43%!important; z-index:0;" alt=""></a>
<a id="savethepub" class="tab-base navbar-brand navbar-brand position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" style="top: 84%!important; font-size:22px;" href="#">Save The British Pub</a>
```

I am having an issue with JQuery, my code above is the HTML and is all correct, and the code below targets a button on the page. I have checked using test and the button works however the CSS isnt applying.

```
var button = $( "#collapser" );
var tabimg = $( "#icon-img" );
var stp = $( "#savethepub" );

var bntclicked = false;

button.click(function() {
    if (bntclicked === false) {
        tabimg.css({"max-width":"70px", "top":"8%!important", "left":"21%!important", "z-index":"0"})
        stp.css({"font-size":"22px", "top":"7%!important"})

        bntclicked = true;
    }
    else if (bntclicked === true) {
        tabimg.css({"max-width":"113px", "top":"43%!important", "left":"50%!important", "z-index":"0"})
        stp.css({"font-size":"22px", "top":"84%!important"})

        bntclicked = false;
    }
});
```

Button Code:

```
<button id="collapser" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
```

Comment: Have you tried `fontSize` instead? JavaScript CSS rules are camelCase.

Comment: Can you include the HTML for button `id=collapser`?  If it's `<button type="submit">` (or no `type=` so defaults to `submit`) then it could be your button is POSTing so refreshing the page (see that a lot here).  Add a `return false;` as the last line of your `button.click`

Comment: Note that your `<a id=savethepub` is *already* font-size:22px - so changing it to 22px won't make any difference.  Exactly what is "not applying" ?

Comment: The positioning is not applying, such as moving the image to the left side of the screen instead of central and moving both the image and text to the top of the screen on click and reversing the effects on the second click

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl note it *should* be `font-size` as it's a css property, not a javascript one.    Having said that jquery will convert camel `fontSize` to hyphenated `font-size` - but not `fontsize` - so partially correct :)   https://jsfiddle.net/7afr3hym/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you've included the `!important` flag in the values of the CSS properties in the object you provide to `css()`. These are invalid and need to be removed.

You also need to remove the `!important` flag on the inline styles you have added in the HTML, as they are entirely redundant. Inline styles have the highest precedence so `!important` has no effect there, unless you've included `!important` somewhere else in your stylesheets, which again means that should be removed.

The `!important` flag should be avoided where possible, in favour of using selector precedence. The only real legitimate use for it is when you're attempting to override styles applied by a third party source which you have no control over - and even then rule precedence should be the primary solution.

Try the following example:

```js
var button = $("#collapser");
var tabimg = $("#icon-img");
var stp = $("#savethepub");

var bntclicked = false;

button.click(function() {
  if (bntclicked === false) {
    tabimg.css({
      "max-width": "70px",
      "top": "8%",
      "left": "21%",
      "z-index": "0"
    });
    stp.css({
      "font-size": "22px",
      "top": "7%"
    })

    bntclicked = true;
  } else if (bntclicked === true) {
    tabimg.css({
      "max-width": "113px",
      "top": "43%",
      "left": "50%",
      "z-index": "0"
    });
    stp.css({
      "font-size": "22px",
      "top": "84%"
    });

    bntclicked = false;
  }
});
```

```css
#icon-img { position: absolute; }
#savethepub { position: absolute; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="collapser">Collapser</button>

<a href="https://www.timeatthebar.co.uk" target="_blank">
  <img id="icon-img" src="assets/img/tabicon2.png" class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" style="max-width: 113px; top: 43%; z-index: 0;" alt="">
</a>
<a id="savethepub" class="tab-base navbar-brand navbar-brand position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" style="top: 84%; font-size: 22px;" href="#">Save The British Pub</a>
```

***However*** it should be noted that the logic can be made much simpler if you use classes to apply the styling. The JS logic to update the styling effectively then becomes a single line:

```js
var $button = $("#collapser");
var $tabimg = $("#icon-img");
var $stp = $("#savethepub");

$button.on('click', () => {
  $tabimg.add($stp).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
#icon-img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 113px;
  top: 43%;
  z-index: 0;
}
#icon-img.active {
  max-width: 70px;
  top: 8%;
  left: 21%;
}

#savethepub {
  position: absolute;
  top: 84%;
  font-size: 22px;
}
#savethepub.active {
  top: 7%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="collapser">Collapser</button>

<a href="https://www.timeatthebar.co.uk" target="_blank">
  <img id="icon-img" src="assets/img/tabicon2.png" class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" alt="">
</a>
<a id="savethepub" class="tab-base navbar-brand navbar-brand position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" href="#">Save The British Pub</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is failing is because you are trying to add the !important in the CSS function, and that's not allowed. To make this work as you would like you have a couple options. You could put the desired CSS in a class and then toggle the class (This is what I'd do). Another option is you could use the .attr() function to modify the style attr as a whole. One other option is to use the cssText selector, which allows you to add multiple CSS rules with one key. Example below:

```
// Change width
$('#txt').css({
    'cssText': 'width: 220px !important; font-size: 12px;'
});
```

Here's a link to help: https://makitweb.com/how-to-add-important-to-css-property-with-jquery/

Here's your code with the !important taken out:

```
button.click(function() {
    if (bntclicked === false) {
        tabimg.css({"max-width":"70px", "top":"8%", "left":"21%", "z-index":"0"})
        stp.css({"font-size":"22px", "top":"7%"})

        bntclicked = true;
    }
    else if (bntclicked === true) {
        tabimg.css({"max-width":"113px", "top":"43%", "left":"50%", "z-index":"0"})
        stp.css({"font-size":"22px", "top":"84%"})

        bntclicked = false;
    }
});
```